# Displaying long interface name in network manager applet

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, networkmanager, desktop-environment, i3

When I click on nm-applet indicator and the menu opens, beside the Ethernet Network there is long title like this "Realtek some model PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (model number Motherboard)" which makes the menu width large. Also this string apears on nmcli output for vboxnet1, the discription is simple "vboxnet1".

[image: Screenshot]

How can I make this to not show or get a shorter discription?

Comment: Which DE? Perhaps a screenshot too if possible?

Comment: @Sparhawk what do you mean by DE? added the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. DE is "Desktop Environment" (the tag you used).

Comment: i3 with Arch Linux

Comment: FWIW i3 is a window manager (Arch Linux is the distribution). Normally the DE (or "task bar"?) provides access to the applets, although I'm not sure in this case.

Comment: You are right, The DE is gnome and the taskbar is i3bar, using nm-applet for networks.

Comment: Please edit your question and fix up your tags. (Hover over the `desktop-environment` tag for more info.) This will make it more likely for people to be able to find your question and hence help you. Good luck and welcome to U&L.